# How to express a convex function of a Hermitian operator in terms of its eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, operators

The Hermitian operator $\hat O$ can be expressed as

$$\hat{O}=\sum_i O_i|O_i\rangle\langle O_i|.$$

How to prove that a convex function $f(\hat O)$ can be expressed like

$$f (\hat O)=\sum_i f(O_i)|O_i\rangle\langle O_i|~  ?$$

Comment: At the level functional analysis is done in quantum mechanics, it is rather a definition than something you can prove. On a more abstract and rigorous level you handle it like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus – side note: I guess math.SE might be a better place for this question.

Comment: Side note: Even on the physics level you can easily argue formally with the diagonalizability of the operator, and the fact, that continuous functions can be approximated by polynomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is given in great generality by the beautiful and powerful [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem); in its functional calculus form.

This theorem clarifies the meaning of your first expression, and specifies the functions for which you can write the second (that however are many). In addition, it applies to any self-adjoint operator, bounded or unbounded.

Sadly, the proof and technical statement of the theorem are quite abstract, and difficult to follow without a solid knowledge of functional analysis. For a reasonable introduction you may see the first book by reed and simon (chapter 7, and part of chapter 8). A much more detailed presentation is given by Weidmann in his book "Linear operators in Hilbert spaces".

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need the vectors $|O_k\rangle$ to form an orthonormal system. Then to prove what you need you start with polynomials and verify that, e.g. $O^2$ has the desired form etc... For a continuous function $f$, assuming that $O$ is a bounded operator you can then invoke the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.